# How to customize hover text in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm creating a barplot in plotly (python) with

```
go.Bar(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
    text=['10%', '20%', '30%'],
    textposition='inside',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgba(219, 64, 82, 0.7)',
        line=dict(
            color='rgba(219, 64, 82, 1.0)',
            width=2,
        )
    ),
    base=0)
```

So I'm showing some text inside each bar, now I would also like to add some custom `hovertext` which is composed of custom strings, so different from either `x`, `y` or `text`.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *custom strings*?

Comment: @sentence He is referring to ```customdata``` properties, which are often independent from numerical or categorical data that are used to build the graph. See this source https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-customdata

Comment: @sentence I am simply referring to custom strings, for example when I hover over a point I want to display "foo", when I hover on another I want to display "bar", etc... so associate a custom text to every datapoint (like the `text` field, but shown on hover)

Answer (score 0):

Please add this:

```
go.Bar(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
    text=['10%', '20%', '30%'],
    textposition='inside',
    customdata=['string1','string2', 'string3']
    marker=dict(
        color='rgba(219, 64, 82, 0.7)',
        line=dict(
            color='rgba(219, 64, 82, 1.0)',
            width=2,
        )
    ),
    base=0)
```

See [this part of plotly documentation for reference](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-customdata).

Let me know, if it worked out for you!

Comment: that alone doesn't seem to work, using the `customdata` field or not yields the same result